# I installed TensorRT and CUDNN on Windows for using with yoloV8. Error: Unable to load library: nvinfer_builder_resource.dll

Tags: tensorrt

### Description

I installed TensorRT and CUDNN on Windows for using with yoloV8.
Following nvidia documentation (zip installation): [TensorRT installation documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/archives/tensorrt-861/install-guide/index.html#installing-zip)

But when I ran this code on Python3.11:

```
import tensorrt 
print(tensorrt.__version__) 
assert tensorrt.Builder(tensorrt.Logger())
```

this happens:
[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CFo1.png)

8.6.1

[11/26/2023-11:38:09] [TRT] [E] 6: [libLoader.cpp::nvinfer1::rt::DynamicLibrary::Impl::Impl::290] Error Code 6: Internal Error (Unable to load library: nvinfer_builder_resource.dll)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Project\test-projects\ultra\main.py", line 3, in <module>
assert tensorrt.Builder(tensorrt.Logger())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: pybind11::init(): factory function returned nullptr

**"nvinfer_builder_resource.dll" this file is located on "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.1\bin" and this location is added on system environment path.**

what can I do for resolve this error.

### Environment

**TensorRT Version**: 8.6.1.6

**GPU Type**: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060

**Nvidia Driver Version**: 536.40

**CUDA Version**: 12.1

**CUDNN Version**: 8.9.0.131

**Operating System + Version**: Windows 11

**Python Version (if applicable)**: 3.11

**TensorFlow Version (if applicable)**:

**PyTorch Version (if applicable)**: 2.1.1

**Baremetal or Container (if container which image + tag)**:

### Steps To Reproduce

It can be help you:

```
import torch
import tensorrt
print(tensorrt.__version__)
print(torch.version.cuda)
print(torch.backends.cudnn.version())
```

Output:

8.6.1

12.1

8801

Installation steps for TensorRT:
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/archives/tensorrt-861/install-guide/index.html#installing-zip

Installation steps for CUDNN:
https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#install-windows

**Unable to load library: nvinfer_builder_resource.dll
resolve this error.**